# WebApi 2 route with parameter in path and query

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I recently began migrating an existing web service from WCF to ASP.NET WebApi 2.  One of the legacy endpoints is a little strange, and I'm having issues figuring out how to replicate it in a WebApi controller.  The problem is that the endpoint has query parameter with the same name as part of the path.

In WCF, we had...

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "configuration/id?id={id}")]
Config GetConfigByID(string id);
```

I tried to replicate this in a controller, but clients get 404 errors.

```
[Route("configuration/id")
public IHttpActionResult GetConfigByID(string id)
{
    Config config = GetConfig(id);
    return Ok(config);
}
```

As much as I would like to change the endpoint, I need it to work with existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("configuration/id")
public IHttpActionResult GetConfigByID([FromUri] string id)
{
    Config config = GetConfig(id);
    return Ok(config);
}
```

You can give a try to **FromUri** attribute

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  My exact question works perfectly fine.  Something else within the controller was fat-fingered.  Carry on...